# Get PID of the process that killed my application

Tags: windows, process

How could I detect which process killed my application? Do I need to run another instance which creates a hook on my application or is there an easier way?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I smell some sort of virus being made.

Comment: I want to create an event log what is being killed on the system and what/who is doing it.

Comment: @JamWaffles: or plain and simple *vengeance*. Mutually Assured Destruction for software. ;)

Comment: Guess I won't propose overwriting the prologue of `TerminateProcess` to verify whether the given handle resolves to your own process id. What a nasty, abusive hack...

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK when a process is killed it really doesn't get a chance to log anything. However, Windows can [audit the lifecycle of processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms813609.aspx). So setting up auditing may help you get the information you need.

You can configure this through the *Local Security Policy* control panel, under Local Policies / Audit Policy / Audit Process Tracking.